# Помогите вызвать в React {const}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-hook

`const Change = (individualSpan) => { filterFunction(individualSpan.idNumber); }`

как вызвать эту константу. получается только через onClick={Change} все другие попытки дают ошибки.
вопрос как можно сделать некий вызов этого {Change} без кнопки и нажатия а сразу при загрузке страницы

---

```js
const [products, setProducts] = useState([0]);

const getProducts = async () => {

    const products = await fs.collection('Products').get();
    const productsArray = [];
    for (var snap of products.docs) {
        var data = snap.data();
        data.ID = snap.id;
        productsArray.push({
            ...data
        })
        if (productsArray.length === products.docs.length) {
            setProducts(productsArray);
        }
    }
}

const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    getProducts();

}, [])


function filterFunction(individualSpan) {
    let IDA = window.location.href.split('/').at(-1);
    const filter = products.filter((product) => individualSpan.idNumber=== IDA.toString());
    setFilteredProducts(filter);

}

const Change = (individualSpan) => {
    filterFunction(individualSpan.idNumber);
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки вызова.

Answer (score 0):

я думаю надо использовать хук useEffect, в верхней части компонента добавте `useEffect(()=>Change(),[])`

Comment: Тоже пытался но тогда он пишет ошибку

ERROR

individualSpan is undefined

не может найти individualSpan.
но самое интересное что все это работает с помощью onClick

Comment: тогда нужен полный код , так сложно сказать в чем проблема

Comment: в твоем коде я не вижу откуда берётся individualSpan , где эта переменная инициализирована? что ты передаешь в качестве этой переменной?

Comment: ниоткуда. при нажатии кнопки этот код работает как нистранно

Comment: у тебя функция Change принимает параметр individualSpan, если при вызове его не передать там будет undefined, поэтому я и спрашиваю, что ты туда передаешь?